# Showing dates by day wise, and having default date based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

am attaching a query to bring dates to a field, 
if system time is before 01:00 pm  then it should bring today date+1 else if system date is after or equal 01:00 pm it should bring  today date +2
further , user can see the query result that will show him a date range along side with day names , and select one of them manually if the above cases wasn't what the user is looking for .

queries are avilable and working fine but separately, 
one query bring date range , and one query set the date based on a condition , i need to make them one query , that bring the date ranges and set default date to be based on the conditions;
here are the queries :
Note : Q No 2 , I tried to make both queries as one query but its not bring the correct result , it keep bring today date +1 no matter what system time is.

1)

```
  If DATEPART(Hour,Getdate())<12
    SELECT GetDate()+1

    If DATEPART(Hour,Getdate())>=12
    SELECT GetDate()+2
```

2)

```
If DATEPART(Hour,Getdate())<12
    DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
    SET @Date1 = GetDate()+0
    SET @Date2 = GetDate()+365

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date], DateName(Weekday,DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1)) as dayname
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2

If DATEPART(Hour,Getdate())>=12
    DECLARE @Date3 DATE, @Date4 DATE
    SET @Date3 = GetDate()+2
    SET @Date4 = GetDate()+365

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date3) [Date], DateName(Weekday,DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date3)) as dayname
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date3) < @Date4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to calculate the start date.  The CTE uses a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to tell if it is being run before or after 12.

```
WITH Base AS
    (
        /* Returns the start date based on the current time.
         * Before midday the start date is today.
         * After midday it is the day after tomorrow.
         */
        SELECT
            CASE 
                -- Use current time to calculate start date.
                WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 12 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
                ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())
            END AS StartDate
    )
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, sv.Number + 1, b.StartDate)                    AS [Date],
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, sv.Number + 1, b.StartDate))    AS [DateName]
FROM
    master..spt_values AS sv
        CROSS JOIN Base AS b
WHERE 
    sv.[type] = 'P'
    AND DATEADD(DAY, Number + 1, b.StartDate) < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, b.StartDate)
;
```

Comment: Hello @Release Object ,   Thanks for your help , this will gave the same resualt as query No1 ,   what i need is to bring a date range with days names like in query no 2 ,    but to  set the default date to be based on the condition , so  by default the value of the field will depend in the mentioned condition , but if user want to change the field value , he will see the full range date and select another date

Comment: I've updated my query.  This time the number of days added to the default date is based on the current time.  I've also changed the example to better match your original query.

Comment: Thanks for your effort ,   really appreciate it ,   but it still show the date +1  even the time on system is 5 pm , also dates aren't matching with days names .

Comment: My fault.  As you can probably noticed the CASE statement is returned the Number + 1 before 13:00.  And Number + 3 after.  But the date column is always returning Number + 1.  This needs a second CASE statement.

Comment: I've edited my answer again.  Hopefully I've correctly understood your requirement,